# Regex Search with commas

Tags: python, regex, search

need some help with regards to regex expression.

```
str = 'label1 a1,832,b2 and label2 2, c45'
```

trying to return the results as

```
['label a1',label 832','label b2','label 2', 'label c45']
```

so far am able to get only `['label2 a1','label2 2']`

thanks!

edit:

for clarification.

I have a list of labels

```
labelList = ['dog','cat','mouse',...]

str = 'There are 3 locations which are dog 122, h25 and cat a3.'
```

The result should be:

```
result = 'dog 122', 'dog h25' and 'cat a3'.
```

Currently I'm doing a regex search as such:

```
for x in labelList:
    re.search(r'\b(%s) ([^ \r\n]+\b')
```

Hope this clarifies the question!

edit2:

```
labelList = ['dog','cat','mouse',...]

str = 'There are 3 locations which are dog 122, h25 and cat a3.'

for x in labelList:

    if re.search(r'\b(%s)\b' % (x), str):

        nr = [f"(%s) {m}" % (x) for m in re.findall(r"(?:(%s))?(\w+)",  comText) if m!= 'and']
        print(nr)
```

However, the output seems to be wrong. It gives me the following output

```
["(dog) (' ','there')", "(dog) (' ','are')", "(dog) (' ', '3')" ...
```

Comment: *so far am able to get only...*, where is the code that you have tried to get you this far?

Comment: Use split, https://docs.python.org/2/library/stdtypes.html#str.split

Comment: We can give you tips on your regular expressions if you include them.

Comment: `a1`, `832`, `2` and `c45` have the common characteristic that they are all immediately followed by a comma or are at the end of a line. We can match those with `\w+(?=,|$)`. What about `b2`? What is the *rule* that tells us that you wish to extract that string as well? You need to begin by telling us, in words, the matching rules, then give an example for illustration. Questions stated in terms of a single example are rarely unambiguous, and this is not an exception.

Comment: Is `"label"` a given, or could the string be `'cat1 a1,832,b2 and cat2 2, c45'`, in which case you would want `['cat a1', 'cat 832','cat b2', 'cat 2', 'cat c45']` returned?

Comment: 'dog' is even better (says my canine companion, Saffi, who saw your comment). I am asking whether `"label"`, `"cat"` or `"dog"` are to be determined by processing the string or whether we know the string contains the literal `"label"`, which is to be used in the return value.

Comment: I think you need to edit your desired output example if it's not exactly like what you really want. Because it looks to me like you want to take instances like `label1` and make `label 1`, and make the following substrings each a label like `label 832` rather than `label1 832`.

Comment: Updated the question based on suggestions. thanks!

Comment: match a string in the label_list, then form labels from the following comma delimited strings up to the word 'and'.  Does that sum it up?

Comment: yes correct. labelList contains strings to search the string.

Answer (score 0):

Alright. So far, I have a way to extract the text following one of the labels up to either a period, or the word "and".

```
>>> target_str = 'There are 3 locations which are dog 122, h25 and cat a3.'
>>> label_list = ['dog', 'cat', 'mouse', 'wombat']
>>> 
>>> expr = r"\b(" + '|'.join(label_list) + r")(.*?)(?:and|\.)"
>>>
>>> label_expr = re.compile(expr)  # Put somwhere it will only be compiled once.
>>>
>>> new_label_list = [f"{species} {tag}" 
...                   for species, tags in label_expr.findall(target_str)
...                   for tag in re.findall(r"\w+", tags)]
>>> new_label_list
['dog 122', 'dog h25', 'cat a3']
>>>
```

The labels are extracted in two phases. First we get a list of tuples where the first item is the species (dog, cat), and the second a raw list of tags (or labels). Then that's iterated over to build the final labels.

If compiling the expression, put the compilation code somewhere where it only needs to be executed once - otherwise what's the point in compiling it.

Or using `.finditer()` instead of `.findall()`.

```
>>> new_label_list = [f"{m.group(1)} {tag}"
...                   for m in label_expr.finditer(target_str)
...                   for tag in re.findall(r"\w+", m.group(2))]
>>> new_label_list
['dog 122', 'dog h25', 'cat a3']
```

Comment: thanks for the answer! 

i have a list of labels where labelList = [label1, label2, label3... ] 

so the label1 and label2 are unique labels. so how should i adapt the code instead?

Comment: You can post some more examples of the target text you have to parse if the above doesn't handle all the cases @datajem

Comment: Yes this is. Thank you.

Comment: If you found any solutions helpful, it doesn't hurt to give them an upvote @datajem ;-)

Comment: Have tried to upvote. Less than 15 reputation tho so does not reflect on the publicly displayed score. Thanks Todd!

Answer (score 0):

Try this one out:

```
import re
str = 'label1 a1,832,b2 and label2 2, c45'
str = str.replace('and', ',')
str = re.sub(r"label[0-9]+", "", str)
labels = ['label {}'.format(x.strip()) for x in str.split(',')]
```

The output is:

```
labels = ['label a1', 'label 832', 'label b2', 'label 2', 'label c45']
```

As I see it, you have `label[0-9]+` and the sub-string `and` as useless information.
Just remove it and extract label names. Then reconstruct the strings using `string.format()` function

Comment: Using f-strings would be simpler syntax.